# React Child Component Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am creating hierarchical React Component using JSX. The code does not show any errors but nothing shows up on my page. Here is my code below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>React Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var Converter = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <inputBox />;
            }
        });

        var inputBox = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(Converter, null),
            document.getElementById('app'),
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i use

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(inputBox, null),
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Hello World!** Shows up. What am I doing wrong? I have tried debugging a lot but could not figure out anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            return <InputBox />;
```

and NOT

```
            return <inputBox />;
```

Do not use lowercase when you are initiating react component. Otherwise, it will be considered as simple HTML tag.

Comment: You are awesome. I have spend last 5 hours debugging that and could not figure out this thing. The components should always have camel case starting with a capital. You rock man!

Comment: Your are Welcome  .

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
var inputBox = React.createClass({
```

Use this:

```
var InputBox = React.createClass({
```

Because react component must start with uppercase otherwise it will be treated as html elements.

Check the working snippet:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>React Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
        var Converter = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <InputBox />;
            }
        });

        var InputBox = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Converter/>,
            document.getElementById('app'),
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```